# How are values passed in F# for Functions?

Tags: function, f#, functional-programming

It is my first day of learning F#. I am going through tryfsharp.org when I came across following example for topic **Functions as Values**

```
let chrisTest test =
 test "Chris"
let isMe x =
 if x = "Chris" then
    "it is Chris!"
 else
    "it's someone else"
chrisTest isMe
```

**Explanation on the site:-**
chrisTest is a simple higher order function that executes a test against a string value. The isMe function checks to see if a string is equal to "Chris". Passing isChris to chrisTest passes the string "Chris" as an argument to the `isChris" function, and returns the result of "it is Chris!".

My thought:- Value of `isMe` function is passed to function `chrisTest` in the last line of program. However what I do not get is there is no value passed to `isMe` function. How does `isMe` function decide to execute what value to return?

Comment: `chrisTest` is passing `"Chris"` to every argument you are giving it (yeah the argument is a function - therefore *higher order*) - so when you pass `isMe` to `chrisTest` the last one passes `"Chris"` to `isMe` and returns the result back (in this case `"it is Chris!"`) - you can try this by changing the `test "Chris"` into something different (like `test "Christine"`)

Comment: Deduction:- So the order of Functions executing matters and therefore `chrisTest` is executed first and the its value `'chris'` is passed to `isMe`.
Question:- Are we passing `chrisTest` to `isMe` or `isMe` to `chrisTest`? Or it is written because `chrisTest` is higher order and therefore executed first therefore written as `chrisTest isMe` and not as `isMe chrisTesst`

Comment: As John Palmer answered, you can use substitutions to gradually reduce and simplify the code, one step at a time.  First, replace `chrisTest isMe` with the definition of `chrisTest`, and the value of the `test` parameter is `isMe`, giving you `isMe "Chris"`. Then replace `isMe` with its definition, where `x` is replaced with `"Chris"` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

For this case we can start by replacing everything in christest.  Then you have

```
chrisTest isMe = isme "Chris" (as test=isme)
```

and then the rest follows by a similar procedure

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you feed it into F# interactive so you can look at the types as you go:

```
let chrisTest test = test "Chris";;
```

> val chrisTest : test:(string -> 'a) -> 'a

Here we have a function which we can supply another function as an argument (called test)  from `string -> 'a`, it will call this supplied function with the argument "Chris", returning some result `'a`.

```
let isMe x =
    if x = "Chris" then
        "it is Chris!"
     else
        "it's someone else";;
```

> val isMe : x:string -> string

Here we have our simple name-checking function.

Notice that this `isMe` function is suitable to be supplied as an argument to the `christTest` function.  Notice also that if the argument we supply `chrisTest` with is of type `string -> string`, we are going to get a `string` result.  Hopefully you can see here how you can use the type signatures to help you reason about the behaviour of your program.

So, when we supply `isMe` as an argument to `chrisTest`, the `chrisTest` function runs the `isMe` function with the argument "Chris", returning the result "it is Chris!".